# How to assign a new variable without mapping using Automapper

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core, automapper

I want to set PasswordSalt directly, without mapping it from any of the properties available in the DTO.

```
public class SaveUserRequestDTOProfile: Profile
{
    public SaveUserRequestDTOProfile()
    {
        var salt = GenerateSalt();

        .ForMember(m => m.Username, map => map.MapFrom(s => s.Username))
        .ForMember(m => m.PasswordSalt, salt); // this doesn't work

    }
}
```

Thanks in Advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You would map it in the same way as Username, only you would specify the value you created, for instance

```
public class SaveUserRequestDTOProfile: Profile
{
  public SaveUserRequestDTOProfile()
  {
    var salt = GenerateSalt();

    .ForMember(m => m.Username, map => map.MapFrom(s => s.Username))
    .ForMember(m => m.PasswordSalt, map => map.MapFrom(_ => salt));

  }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You can just specify any value in the `MapFrom` method. It's not a requirement that the value must actually come from the source object:

```
.ForMember(m => m.PasswordSalt, map => map.MapFrom(s => salt));
```